# Pronunciation of "sure" in American English

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

I saw that "sure" can be pronounced [ʃʊər] or [ʃər] in the dictionary.
Here's my audio: https://clyp.it/4gdwhi24 First I pronounce it [ʃʊər] then [ʃər]

I don't know which one should I use, or is this more of a preference? or a difference between regions? some Americans pronounce it [ʃʊər] and some [ʃər]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one sounds great to me!. (As an American) I don't really ever hear people pronounce it the first way (with an 'or' sound like in "shore" and "oar"). I almost always hear it the way you pronounce it the second time, with an 'er' (like in "her" and "fur"). Another way you can pronounce it is to pronounce the u with an 'oo' sound, so it sounds like "Shoo-er" (rhymes with sewer), although this is not as common. Or at least, not in the midwest where I live. This might be a regional thing.

Answer (score 0):

I almost always hear it the second way, but I'm sure both are fine.

P.S. I'm American, so it may be that it is pronounced the first way more often in England or Australia, but I have no proof of that.